# Controlling different clocks with switches in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, clock

How can I control 2 different clocks? I wrote that `clk1Hz<=newclock or newclock2;` so I was going to be able to control it by choosing one of them is '1'. However, it gives me unexpected identifier error in that sentence(clk1Hz<=newclock or newclock2;). I have no idea why I have such an error there.

```
entity Top_module is
  port(     clk : in std_logic;
    input: in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
    reset: in std_logic;
    output: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
  );
end Top_module;
```

architecture Behavioral of Top_module is

```
component Clockdivider  
    port( clock : in std_logic;
        newclock : out std_logic;--for 1/4sec
        newclock2: out std_logic--for 1/20 sec
    );
end component;

signal state :std_logic_vector(3 downto 0):= "0000";
signal clk1Hz : std_logic;

clk1Hz<=newclock or newclock2;
begin
    comp1: Clockdivider port map(clk, clk1Hz);

    process(clk1Hz,reset)
    begin

      if(rising_edge(clk1Hz)) then
        if newclock='1' then --this is for 1/4 sec option
        ...
        elsif newclock2='1' then
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping of clockdivider's ports is not corresponding to it's declaration. It has one input and two outputs. The port mapping should go like this:

```
signal newclock : std_logic;
signal newclock2 : std_logic; 
.......
comp1: Clockdivider port map(clk, newclock, newclock2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your clk1Hz signal is assigned inside the architecture head -> move it after begin (architecture body).

But your design has more drastic problems:

- A OR-gate is not a selection circuit, that would be a multiplexer.
- But, you *can not* multiplex two clock signals with normal logic.

Which test platform are you using?
ASIC/FPGA, Xilinx/Altera/..., Spartan/Virtex/.../Cyclon/Stratix/... ?

For example: If you are using a Xilinx FPGA device, then you should use a `BUFGCTRL` to switch two clock signals. This is a very advanced technique, so I would suggest to review your design and use a solution without clock-multiplexing :)